# TcpClient.GetStream().CopyTo(MemoryStream) stops application from continuing?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, stream

I'm trying to perform some extremely basic network operations, yet I'm having some trouble.

Originally, I was trying to use `NetworkStream.Length` to create a new `byte[]`, but it became apparent that this is not possible since `NetworkStream` does not support seek operations.

I then found some examples showing how to copy the `NetworkStream` to a `MemoryStream`, which allows seek operations. So far, so good.

Or is it?

Once the scope of the `using` statement gets hit, the application essentially stops. It's still running, doing *something*, but I can't really tell what. Here's the code:

```
    void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;

        //copy client stream to memory stream to allow seek operations
        MemoryStream clientStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var clientRequestStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
        {
            clientRequestStream.CopyTo(clientStream);
        }

        //...
    }
```

So there's where my problem has me completely stumped. I need to copy my `NetworkStream` to a `MemoryStream` to do some processing, but this task alone is proving more difficult than it should be.

Has anybody encountered this issue before?

Comment: use a thread instead of doing the work on your ui thread.

Comment: or you could read chunks at a time.

Comment: don't use `CopyTo` use `Read`.

Comment: A Stream doesn't end until the connection is closed so your copy won't return until that occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TCP stream is often *not terminated* - i.e. the inbound stream is technically alive until the socket is broken (or at a minimum : the other end of the socket elects to close their outbound link, perhaps keeping their inbound link open to get the reply).

Now: `CopyTo` will want to read to the **end** of the stream. Of a stream that *has no end*. The behaviour of `Read` is:

- block until at least one byte is available...
- or until the stream is closed...
- or until a timeout

If timeouts aren't enabled, and the socket doesn't close ever, then: boom.

For this reason, socket code usually needs to be very careful in terms of "framing" - i.e. knowing how much data to read as a unit. This is often done via some form length-prefix in the data stream, i.e. "the next message is 27 bytes" - then you know to only try to read 27 more bytes, because reading a 28th might block you forever. In text-based protocols, this is often done using sentinel values like line-feed.