# SerializationException: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed

Tags: c#, exception, networkstream

This is inherited code that sometimes fails but I can not figure out why.

```
using(NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream()) {
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, message_);
    if(responseHandler_ != null) {
        Message response = (Message) formatter.Deserialize(stream); // <-- fails here
        responseHandler_(response, stream);   
    }
}
```

I have googled it to death. I have tried seeking suggestions but NetworkStream can not seek.

Edit: It doesn't always fail. Only on occasion. 
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Before Deserializing try setting the position to 0 `formatter.Position = 0;`

Comment: @MXD not every stream support this.

Answer (score 0):

In such case I'd suggest copying your `NetworkStream` to `MemoryStream`, which can seek - you can find very good examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/how-do-i-copy-the-contents-of-one-stream-to-another).

With `MemoryStream`, you can reset stream's location after it is serialized

```
using(var ms = new MemoryStream(stream) {
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(ms , message_);
    if(responseHandler_ != null) {
        ms.Location = 0;
        Message response = (Message) formatter.Deserialize(ms); 
        responseHandler_(response, ms);   
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I turn stream = client.GetStream into a byte array that MemoryStream can take in the constructor.

I tried this, but after CopyTo the code hangs

    var output = new MemoryStream();
 stream.CopyTo(output);

Comment: @malcie please refer to the hyperlink I added - you can use `CopyTo` method and copy from one stream to another or just a custom method.

Comment: I tried CopyTo but it hangs there. 

I now have

using(client) {
 using(NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream()) {
  using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
   stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
   BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
   formatter.Serialize(memoryStream , message_);
   if(responseHandler_ != null) {
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    Message response = (Message) formatter.Deserialize(memoryStream); 
    responseHandler_(response, memoryStream);   
   }
  }
 }
}

Comment: Why can't I format this code and Enter submits the comment rather than CR.

Comment: @malcie Can you show how you implemented `CopyTo` and where it hangs exactly?

Comment: I did but it didn't format (above). Not sure how to format as it removes all Carriage Returns???

Comment: @malcie perform `CopyTo` before `using` statement. TBH I don't think it will be needed anyway.

Comment: I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328184/tcpclient-getstream-copytomemorystream-stops-application-from-continuing) but I am not sure how to solve it :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at the sending side. Adding a "linger" option solved it.

client.LingerState = new LingerOption (true, 10);